# XML element check

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a **XML** file

```
<catalog>
    <cd>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <state>USA</state>        
    </cd>
    <cd>
        <title>Hide your heart</title>
        <artist>Bonnie Tyler</artist>
        <country>UK</country>       
    </cd>
</catalog>
```

I am writing an XSLT file to create a table with proper table Header.
When `xsl:element= state`, the table header should be `State` and when `xsl:element=Country`, the table header should be `country`.

```
<xsl:choose>
    <tr>
        <xsl:when test="element name='state'">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>Collection </b>
                </td>
                <td> 
                    <table border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Artist</th>
                            <th>State</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="artist" />
                            ></td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="state" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:when test="element name='country'">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <b>Collection </b>
                </td>
                <td> 
                    <table border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Artist</th>
                            <th>Country</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="artist" />
                            ></td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="country" />
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </xsl:when>

        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>Error</xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </tr>
</xsl:choose>
```

Basically I need to use if or when condition for xml elements

Comment: XSLT has both `xsl:if` as well as `xsl:choose`/`xsl:when`/`xsl:otherwise` constructs. Did you try them?

Comment: yeah i tried, but not sure am right

                       <xsl:choose>
                      <xsl:when test="xsl:element = 'state' ">
                      <xsl:value-of select="state" />
                        </xsl:when>
                         </xsl:choose>

This is what i know and trying

Comment: so under when how should i write the condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XPath `<xsl:when...>` expressions were wrong. You used `<xsl:when test="element name='state'">` instead of the correct

```
<xsl:when test="state">
```

which tests if there is an element `state` present as a child of a `<cd>` element. The same error was present with the second `<xsl:when...>`.

So use these XSLT templates for the right output:

```
<xsl:template match="/catalog" >     <!-- only for completeness of illustration -->
    <table border="1">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cd" >           <!-- will be applied to all <cd> elements -->
    <tr>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="state">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Collection 1</b>
                    </td>
                    <td> 
                        <table border="1">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Artist</th>
                                <th>State</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="artist" />
                                ></td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="state" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="country">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <b>Collection 2</b>
                    </td>
                    <td> 
                        <table border="1">
                            <tr>
                                <th>Artist</th>
                                <th>Country</th>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="artist" />
                                ></td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select="country" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>Error</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Fine , I am using this now. Thank you.